# Calling Jasperreports from Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

Anyone who can suggest how to call .jasper report file from Oracle forms 6i

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution

```
v_url := '<your url to the report>';
host ('cmd /c start '||v_url);
```

But I am not sure if there are any better alternatives

Answer (score -1):

Several years ago I implemented something similar for Oracle Forms 6i(terminal version).

- Application running Oracle Forms 6i sent XML data via email onto some "mail service".
- This was implemented as simple Perl script executed as milter filter.
- This script then executed XEP and generated PDF document from XML data
- This PDF document was sent via email into users mailbox

Comment: thanks for the reply, in my scenario I have the compiled version of my report file (.jasper) now what will be the next step for calling it from Oracle forms